# How can I calculate filter parameters between RF switch and antenna?

Tags: antenna, impedance-matching, low-pass, high-pass-filter

In the schematics [en.MB1389-WL55JC-highband-E02_Schematic](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/layouts_and_diagrams/schematic_pack/group1/2e/e5/94/2a/d7/46/48/57/MB1389-WL55JC-highband-E02_Schematic/files/MB1389-WL55JC-highband-E02_Schematic.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.MB1389-WL55JC-highband-E02_Schematic.pdf),
there's a Pi filter following the RF switch before it links to the SMA connector for the antenna.
[image]

Upon calculation, I found that the cutoff frequency of this low-pass pi filter is approximately 1800 MHz, which is significantly higher than the 870 MHz of LoraWAN frequencies this schematics is built for.
Could someone clarify what could be the intention behind including this section in the schematics?
Ultimately, I intend to integrate a chip antenna onto the PCB and eliminate the SMA connector.
Should I retain these filters, or do I need to adjust the values of the pi filter components?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a low-pass pi-filter that is used to match the impedance of the antenna to the port impedance of the RF switch (taking into account that it is in series with 33 pF). For the values shown, I would say that its region of operation is pretty close to 900 MHz but, without details of the antenna and port it's impossible to say exactly what impedances it attempts to match.

> *Upon calculation, I found that the cut off frequency of this low-pass
> pi filter is approximately 1800 MHz*

That is incorrect; it is 939.3 MHz and pretty-much about right for impedance matching (slightly above the nominal operating frequency) for a low-pass pi filter.

Comment: Thank you very much for responding. If I understand correctly, the section of the schematics is intended for impedance matching with the antenna. Therefore, if I were to substitute the external antenna with a chip antenna on the PCB, could I then omit those components and incorporate the suggested ones from the chip antenna reference designs?
example antenna: https://productfinder.pulseeng.com/products/datasheets/W3000.pdf

Comment: There are two problems in what you ask. (1) you don't really know what impedance is being matched in your current circuit so you can't then assume (2) that you modify the network if a different antenna is used because critical things like transmission lines between antenna->pi-filter->RF-switch are unknown. Without knowing the impedance of the RF-switch also means you have to dig deeper.